# PHP running out of memory when resizing images

Tags: php

I wrote a script to try and re-size the dimensions of an image to a target (25kb in my example). However sometimes I am getting

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5529 bytes)
```

during the process. Maybe there is some technique (I tried unset()) to free up space during this loop.

```
private function resizeTo($target){
    $x = 9;
    for($x; $x > 0; $x--){
        // Expose w/h from $this->info
        list($width, $height) = $this->info;
        $newWidth = $width * $x / 10;           
        $newHeight = ($height / $width) * $newWidth;
        $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);

        if (file_exists($this->finalPath)) 
            unlink($this->finalPath);

        imagepng($tmp, $this->finalPath);
        if(filesize($this->finalPath) <= $target) return true;
        else unset($tmp);
    }
    $this->error = "Could not resize to $target kb after 10 attempts. Please upload a smaller image.";
}
```

The image comes from a form upload in $_FILES[].

The hard-to-discern part is it will fail on an image that is 200kb, but pass on an (particular) image that is 330 kb.. So I'm not sure what the exact reason or incoming file size determines the failure.

Comment: Filesize isn't the issue with images, it's all about resultion.... you need width * height * 4 bytes of memory for the image

Comment: Filesize is 100% my issue, and I am trying to lower it by lowering the resolution (W*H).

Comment: Image filesize isn't what takes up memory in PHP, image resolution takes up memory, as per what I said above

Comment: Filesize depends on resolution. However have you tried to increase your memory limit ?

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying. The file that is giving me issues is 2048x1536 so that makes sense. Thanks. And no @steven I don't have that control.

Answer (score 0):

If we hopefully think that one resampling of image is ok than you should try to do `imagedestroy($tmp);` instead of unset. Haven't tested how it's affects memory it but should actually destroy resource.